# SQL (MySQLi) best fit for text comparation

Tags: mysql

i have the following scenario:
DB table of addresses linked with region ID. Based on address, the workers sorting the packets (QR scanning) to the shelves and re-distributing them to the warehouses all around the capitol city. So far so good, everything seems OK, but there is a problem:
My DB table (MySQL) has the following fields:

```
ID (*auto increment, PK)*
STREET_NAT (*local name of the street - Cyrillic*) UTF8
STREET_EN (*English name of the street - Latin*) UTF8
REGION_ID (*number from 1 to 116  , that describes in what part of the town (warehouse) will be the package distributed*)
```

The problem is, sometimes the addresses are not correctly written plus as a bonus, sometimes they are in Cyrillic, sometimes in Latin.

I need to create a sorting system that analyzes the best fit of the street address and decides in which part of the city will travel the package. But the people makes mistakes (for example they are not entering "*Jules Verne str.*" , but "*Jul Vern st.*"  , or even in Cyrillic with mistakes.

So my question: Does exists some procedure/method in MySQL to guess the best fit for the address? I am thinking in point system based on

php:

```
    $query = " 
    SELECT REGION_ID FROM ADDRESSES WHERE STREET_NAT LIKE '%{$scanned_address}%' 
OR STREET_EN LIKE '%{$scanned_address}%' "
```

this system works in approx 55% of the cases,when the sender of the package does not makes a mistake. I need to improve this select to add something like "Points" how close is the scanned address to the database field value. Best fit wins, and the region ID will be shown and sorted to the corresponding shelve. I am talking about thousands of packets / day.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea, create a table with the street correct names in it, in Israel we have this data for free, then you can compare from what the user types to the data in your database table with the correct street names. so it's auto complete.
you don't need to insert the values your self. just find a data source that can provide you this data, and it will be autocomplete for the user.

Comment: Problem is, that customers writing addresses by hand (keyboard), not some system. It's something like post office. They are making mistakes very often. I have database of streets from the free source and in my DB every address is correct. I have no chance to auto-correct user inputs.  I will need to solve my problem on PHP level, not on database level i guess. With memory/resource expensive while-cycles